# Ubuntu-Budgie 21.04--When Display shuts off due to idleness, it doesn't come back on

Tags: 21.04, budgie, idle

This has been happening for the past couple days. When the display shuts off, it doesn't come back on when I move the mouse or hit something on the keyboard. The monitor wakes up for a second and flashes "no input" before shutting off again. I know the OS is still active because if I press Ctrl+alt+F2, I can get to the terminal. From there, I can do ctrl+alt+F7 and it brings me back to the GUI. Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to diagnose?